# add members of wheel group, sudo access

Tags: permissions, security, sudo

On Fedora15, following this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo), I added a user to wheel group, which is already in the sudoer config file.

but still I get not-a-sudoer error prompt. Should I specifically name every member of a group in sudoer file to be able to sudo with that user?

Comment: Check if there is line about `wheel` group in sudo config file and if it is not commented. Also after modification of groups you need to logout and log in again...

Comment: yeap, the **logout** thing was the problem!
Thanks @pbm

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have a comment in your /etc/sudoers file infront of the wheel group.

Often you will see this :

```
  ## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
  #%wheel   ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Uncomment the %wheel so it looks like this :

```
  ## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
  %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```